# Prestashop Populate database tables error

Tags: php, mysql, browser, prestashop

Today I tried to install Prestashop (I tried it before)
But it wouldn't work. Here is how I did (Image gallery): http://goo.gl/hiqE3
I don't really know what went wrong, and I tried at least 6 times to download all files, delete all files from server, delete the database, re-upload the files and try again. But it didn't work
At the last part it says "Populate database tables"

I can see there is a lot of people on the internet (like http://goo.gl/AiI0P) that have the same problem, but all the guides didn't really work for me (I may do it wrong).

But I found the sollution

Answer (score 0):

I could just open firefox and do exactly the same as I did in Chrome. And then it worked. Pretty weird, but true

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed prestashop version 1.6.0.9 onto my VPS. Running debian 7.

I had used the process as described in the documentation, download, unzip and then copy over to the server.

During instal I had the exact same error you where getting.
My solution involved copying the zip file to the server, rather than the collection of unzipped files.

I guess that during copying the files an error had caused a corruption of a file. anyway, after this the install ran perfectly.

D

Answer (score 0):

cd to presta installation directory. cd to log folder. in this folder there are log files like 20150102_installation.log.
read the content of file to get more wise of error cause.